# Why only first plot is not labeled with a shape, unlike the rest of plots in the graph?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am trying to plot points on `lineChartView` class. I then plotted data on it, but I see a very funny thing. The second plot is labeled, but not the first one.

[image]

I am setting up `LineChartView` instance and named it `lineChart`:

```
var lineChart: LineChartView = {
   var l = LineChartView()
    l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    l.backgroundColor = .white
    return l
}()
```

`lineChartDataPoints` holds `ChartDataEntry` classes, which holds `x` and `y` values:

```
var lineChartDataPoints: [ChartDataEntry] = []
```

I loop over xData and append `ChartDataEntry` class to `lineChartDataPoints`. `xData` and `yData` variable hold `x` and `y` values: (Which is generated in other function and not really a point of this question)

```
 for i in 0..<xData.count {

        let data = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i + 1), y: Double(yData[i])!)
        lineChartDataPoints.append(data)
    }
```

Then I add `lineChartDataPoints` to `LineChartDataSet`:

```
let lineDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartDataPoints, label: "Values")
```

Then `lineDataSet` is added to `lineData` after setting parameters.

```
 lineDataSet.colors = [UIColor.red]
 lineDataSet.lineWidth = 5
 lineDataSet.circleColors = [UIColor.blue]
 lineDataSet.circleRadius = 5

 lineData.addDataSet(lineDataSet)
```

And this is obviously not because there is only one point. Because I tried this:

```
print("data \(lineChartDataPoints)")

// data [ChartDataEntry, x: 1.0, y 1.0, ChartDataEntry, x: 6.0, y 1.0]
```

There definitely are two points supplied for the graph to display, but I am pretty stumped on why first point won't be labeled with blue dot like second point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before installing the new Charts framework (Version 3.2) for Swift 5, I did not have this issue. There were some tweaks to be made in Charts framework. Installing newest patch (3.3) have solved this problem. So update to the latest version of this framework to avoid this problem.